# Negative or zero chapter number not appearing in list of figures (lof)

Tags: floats, numbering, chapters

Usually figures 1,2,3 of chapter n appears as "n.1, n.2, n.3" in main text and in List of Figures (lof) but this format is not respected if n <= 0, in this case figures appear simply as "1, 2, 3" and the correct format "n.x" show up again only when n > 0.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: This is true in the standard `book` class, but `scrbook` gives the "expected" nubbering Figure -1.1 etc.  Not sure why you would want that though.

Answer (score 5):

In  `book.cls` you can find the following code:

```
\renewcommand \thefigure
     {\ifnum \c@chapter>\z@ \thechapter.\fi \@arabic\c@figure}
```

This sets the behavior you see.  If you want to change it, just redefine `\thefigure`, deleting the check for positive chapter number:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand \thefigure
         {\thechapter.\@arabic\c@figure}
\makeatother
```

You need the `\makeatletter`-`\makeatother` pair because the code uses `@`.

Note that neither the standard behavior nor the one you want is, strictly speaking, "better":  this is the question of taste.  For me "Figure 0.4" or "Figure -1.5" look strange - but if these are your requirements, go ahead and implement them.

Comment: Works! many thanks (btw: I needed Figure 0.4 for the prologue...)